# Disappeared widget bar in the admin panel (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, widget

Witam,

Welcome,

The widget bar disappeared in the admin panel (Wordpress), despite the fact that they are visible on the page. How do I get it back?

I enclose two screens, the [first](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11254269/widgets.JPG) is ok, the [second](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11254269/widgets_eng.JPG) is the error:

Regards,
d4rq000z

Comment: Well it certainly doesn't help that your install is ancient. Could be a corrupt plugin causing the error.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/where-is-widget-data-stored-in-the-database